# JSON inner field parsing with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I am new to JSON and I love how incredibly potent and straight-forward GSON Api can be, compared to any other parsing methods I've researched.
I want to parse a rather complex JSON(using GSON) that resembles the following one in terms of structure:

```
[
  {  
  "name": "Steve",
  "age": 42,
  "description": null,
  "email1": "steve@example.com",
  "email2": null,
  "address1": {
    "type": "home",
    "shippingMethod": "Charge by quantity",
    "street": "Sunrise Ave",
    "streetNo": 17
     },
   "address2": {
    "type": "office",
    "shippingMethod": null,
    "street": "Sunset Ave",
    "streetNo": 71
     },
   "anotherField": "another value"
   },
   {
   "name": "Johnny",
   ...
   "anotherField": "some other value"
   }
]
```

I can see that I need to wrap it up with an array of Client objects, because my JSON starts with a "[" and I can also see I need another container class for the inner fields address1 and address2. This is the container I came up with:

```
public class Client {
  String name;
  int age;
  String description;
  String email1;
  String email2;
  ClientAddress address1;
  ClientAddress address2;
  String anotherfield;
  ..
  getters() and setters()

  public class ClientAddress {
    String type;
    String shippingMethod;
    String street;
    int streetNo;
    ..
    getters() and setters()
  }
}
```

The instruction I wrote to grab the data and populate the wrapper fields is:

```
Client[] clientsArray= (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonClients, Client[].class);
```

The result is only partially satisfying; I managed to access all the primitive fields (such as name,email1..), but the address1 and address2 fields are both null. As a result,

```
clientsArray[i].getAddress1().getShippingMethod();
```

returns a null String.

Where did I go wrong?
Is there a particular way of creating the classes that I am missing?

Note: My JSON object is perfectly valid from a structure standpoint of view. If you see any errors, it's probably because they slipped when I was manually creating the above dummy/demo.

Comment: I noticed in your `JSON` : `"shippingMethod": null,`. Are you sure you're not getting one of those? And `address1` and `address2` cannot be null, otherwise you'd be getting a NPE when  trying to invoke methods on a null reference.

Comment: @vinitius Ok, so you are saying that a "blank" field in a JSON should be something like "shippingMethod": "", "not shippingMethod": null, otherwise it throws NPE?
Same applies for fields that have their own fields? (in my case address1 and address2) ?

Comment: @Razvan No. The `JSON` is ok. I'm saying: **Are you sure you are not getting one of this cases when the shippingMethod is really null?**  I meant that if address1 and adress2 were null , you'd be getting an exception here. So `GSON` seems to be parsing the json as expected. I'm not seeing any mistakes related to your class and the json you posted

Comment: @vinitius What I am getting are null values for fields that are not primtive (address1 and address2), although if I go into debugging perspective and check the JSON string, the address1 and address2 fields are there.

Comment: @Razvan If address1 were `null` the statement :  `clientsArray[i].getAddress1().getShippingMethod();` would throw a `NPE`. Are you getting an exception? If not, then it's not null, but the property `shippingMehtod` may be which would return a `null` string, for instance. As a pointed out in the json you posted, there are cases when this property `shippingMehtod` is , INDEED,  `null`.

Comment: @vinitius 
`clientsArray[0].getName()` returns "Steve" and `clientsArray[0].getAddress1().getShippingMethod()` does indeed throw NPE, because address1 from Client is null.
But that is not how it should be, because if I take a look at the JSON string I am parsing, I can clearly see that the field address1 has information attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow [GSON Collections good practices](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) , try changing

```
 Client[] clientsArray= (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonClients, Client[].class);
```

to

```
 Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Client>>(){}.getType();
 List<Client> clientsArray = (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonClients, collectionType);
```